# How to append image in ng-circle-progress imageSrc option?

Tags: javascript, angular, image, progress-bar, angular7

I am using `ng-circle-progress` to display progress-bar in angular 7.

I followed the steps given here: [Progress-bar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-circle-progress)

Below is **HTML code** to display progress bar:

```
<circle-progress
[percent]="85"
[radius]="23"
[outerStrokeWidth]="3"
[innerStrokeWidth]="3"
[outerStrokeColor]="'#78C000'"
[innerStrokeColor]="'#C7E596'"
[animation]="true"
[animationDuration]="1100"
[showTitle]="false"
[showUnits]="false"
[showSubtitle]="false"
[showImage]="true"
[imageSrc]="/assets/icons/music.svg"
[imageHeight]="23"
[imageWidth]="23"
></circle-progress>
```

But it is throwing an error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'svg' undefined

What could be the possible solution for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[imageSrc]="/assets/icons/music.svg"`

You're providing a variable when you use that syntax.

Switch to **either of those ones, but not a mix of it**

```
imageSrc="/assets/icons/music.svg"
[imageSrc]="'/assets/icons/music.svg'"
```

Comment: This worked: `[imageSrc]="'/assets/icons/music.svg'"`

Comment: @PathikVejani both will work, as I said. Chose the one you like ! If you feel this has resolved your issue, feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer to close your question !

Comment: Yes, I was about to accept but as per Stackoverflow's policy we cannot accept before 15 minutes of the answer given.